# Get parent category tags in template override

Tags: joomla-3.x, template-override, tags, category

I am building a template override for the default featured blog layout. Item tags are displayed with :

```
<?php if ($info == 0 && $params->get('show_tags', 1) && !empty($this->item->tags->itemTags)) : ?>
  <?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.tags', $this->item->tags->itemTags); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This displays the article tags but **is it possible to display the first parent category tags** instead?

Answer (score 2):

I did not remember how to get the parent category of article item, but to get the tags for current category you can try to use this code:

```
$categoryTags = new JHelperTags;
$categoryTags->getItemTags('com_content.category', $item->catid);

<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.tags', $categoryTags->itemTags); ?>
```